# Tomcat8.0.45 using Java app, SQL server and IIS 8.5 on different server

Tags: sql-server, authentication, tomcat8, iis-8.5

I am using Tomcat 8.0.45 to deploy java based web application. I am using IIS 8.5 and BonCode connector. The App uses MS SQL db located on different server and IIS on another. Both are not on the same machine.

Issue:
- I followed steps for integratedSecurity=true, then copying sqljdbc_auth.dll in jre/bin.
- I also followed the steps to configure  tag inside web.config along with userName (AD user) and password.
- I also mapped the user (AD user ) to SQL server db.
- But still I am not able to make it work. On Tomcat startup, I get error.
"Login failed for User 'MyDomain\ServerName$. ClientConnectionId:3b1161.....'.

My above steps could not wrong or incomplete. I can share logs but the above error is what I get in log file.

- Can some one please direct me to any link or provide help here. Please note that mine in java based web app. I found lot of examples but they were all dot net based.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like the error is telling you the problem here; the username or password are wrong. Do the logs on the SQL Server tell you the same thing? It would be beneficial if you include your connection string as well (obviously anonymise your username and password).

Comment: The connection string is same as we do normally i.e. adding 'integratedSecurity=true'. The point is in the error which I pasted above i.e. it prints  ""Login failed for User 'MyDomain\ServerName$" whereas my userName configured is say 'testuser' in web.config. 'ServerName$' is not same as 'testuser'. The serverName$ is my machine name and not user name. So to me it seems, the configuration is not even reading userName='testuser' configured in web.config. Do you know what that '$' stands for in the error.
If you know how to configure things required for my use case then I will try it out

Comment: If it's the same as you normally do, it would likely work; meaning something is different. We can't see your code, or connection string, so how do we help you fix it? You don't ask a mechanic to fix a car without seeing it; the same principle applies here.

Comment: This is the connection string - jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbc.host}:${jdbc.port};database=${jdbc.database};integratedSecurity=true;
But the point is not about connection string. This works fine when both SQL server and IIS (including Tomcat) are running on same server. My case is that they are running on different server. I need to know what additional configuration I need to do apart from the one which I mentioned in my posted question.

Comment: Microsoft only supports HttpPlatformHandler, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/announcing-the-release-of-the-httpplatformhandler-module-for-iis-8/ And then configure the application pool identity to a domain service account, so that your Tomcat process later can use that account to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please elaborate in points which I need to do so that my app works with intergratedSecurity=true with IIS and SQL server running on different server? Not sure why should i need httpPlatformHandler.

Comment: Any help friends ?